# Looking for how to use separate() with multiple separators in R (ClinVar variant data dealing)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, separator, csv

Dear StackOverflow community

I'm a biologist and I'm working with a disease/genetic variants from ClinVar official database. My aim is to extract all gene names, transcripts and variants from this list.

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/clinvar/xml/ClinVarFullRelease_2020-01.xml.gz

However, ClinVar offers the information I need in a single column called "Name". (I've separated some of the values with different results that I want to deal with in the example in the table below:)

```
                                                           Name ClinicalSignificance
1                                        NG_012236.2:g.11027del           Pathogenic
2                    NM_018077.3(RBM28):c.1052T>C (p.Leu351Pro)           Pathogenic
3                                         NC_012920.1:m.7445A>G           Pathogenic
4                                                     m.7510T>C           Pathogenic
5 NC_000023.11:g.(134493178_134493182)_(134501172_134501176)del           Pathogenic
```

(there is other type of data, however since it does not contain the information I need I will treat it as garbage)

I am looking for a way to split the "Name" column in 3 other columns, using multiple separators. I've tried using "|" as part of my regex argument for multiple matches. However, for each time it works, sends the data that has already been separated to a column to the right.
My code:

```
ClinVar_Clean <- separate(ClinVar_Clean, Name, into = c("Transcript","gene.var"),sep = "(?<=\\.[0-9]{1,2})[(]|(?<=[0-9]{3,16}\\.[0-9]{1,2}):|(?=[cmpng]\\.)")
ClinVar_Clean <- separate(ClinVar_Clean, gene.var, into = c("Gene","Variant"),sep = "\\):|(?=[cmpng]\\.)")
```

My result:

```
    Transcript  Gene   Variant ClinicalSignificance
1  NG_012236.2            <NA>           Pathogenic
2  NM_018077.3 RBM28                     Pathogenic
3  NC_012920.1            <NA>           Pathogenic
4                    m.7510T>C           Pathogenic
5 NC_000023.11            <NA>           Pathogenic
```

How the result should look like:

```
    Transcript      Gene   Variant                                                  ClinicalSignificance
1  NG_012236.2              g.11027del                                                  Pathogenic
2  NM_018077.3      RBM28   c.1052T>C (p.Leu351Pro)                                     Pathogenic
3  NC_012920.1              m.7445A>G                                                   Pathogenic
4                           m.7510T>C                                                   Pathogenic
5  NC_000023.11             g.(134493178_134493182)_(134501172_134501176)del            Pathogenic
```

I also tried to execute each separator individually, instead of shifting the data to the right, however it also overwrites the remaining data.

Please if anyone could help, appreciates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do this with one single `extract`/`separate` but I couldn't come up which would give the exact expected output. So here is an attempt breaking it down into separate steps using `str_extract` from `stringr` and `sub` from base R.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Transcript = str_extract(Name, ".*(?<=:)"), 
         Gene = str_extract(Transcript, "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))"), 
         Variant = sub(".*:(.*)", "\\1", Name)) %>%
  select(Transcript, Gene, Variant)

#           Transcript  Gene                                          Variant
#1        NG_012236.2:  <NA>                                       g.11027del
#2 NM_018077.3(RBM28): RBM28                           c.1052T>C(p.Leu351Pro)
#3        NC_012920.1:  <NA>                                        m.7445A>G
#4                <NA>  <NA>                                        m.7510T>C
#5       NC_000023.11:  <NA> g.(134493178_134493182)_(134501172_134501176)del
```

In `Transcript` we capture everything before the colon.

For `Gene`, we get character which is in parenthesis in `Transcript`.

For `Variant`, we get everything after colon.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("m.7510T>C",
"NC_000023.11:g.(134493178_134493182)_(134501172_134501176)del", 
"NC_012920.1:m.7445A>G", "NG_012236.2:g.11027del", 
"NM_018077.3(RBM28):c.1052T>C(p.Leu351Pro)"
), class = "factor"), ClinicalSignificance = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Pathogenic", class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, with little adjustment in the regex, I was able to use the code for all remaining  data!
I was almost using an apply function followed by a lot of if conditions to achieve this result lol
appreciate the help